# Append/supplement data from file1 to file2 (linux)

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have a question can someone advise or give some example of bash script how to fill data from file1 to file2. Below is data which needs to be transfered to file2.

**FILE1 information**

```
// -- ALL LINES BELOW WERE GENERATED --
// -- Some custom text that can be anywhere --
zone "domain40.com" {
    type master;
    file "domain4.com";
    allow-transfer {
            xx.xx.xx.xx;
            2203:d1d0:0:4swd::1;
            common-allow-transfer;
    };
    };
 zone "domain50.com" {
    type master;
    file "domain5.com";
    allow-transfer {
            xx.xx.xx.xx;
            2203:d1d0:0:4swd::1;
            common-allow-transfer;
    };
    };
 ..............
```

**FILE2 information**

```
zone "domain10.com" {
    type master;
    file "domain10.com";
    allow-transfer {
            xx.xx.xx.xx;
            2203:d1d0:0:4swd::1;
            common-allow-transfer;
    };
    };
 zone "domain12.com" {
    type master;
    file "domain12.com";
    allow-transfer {
            xx.xx.xx.xx;
            2203:d1d0:0:4swd::1;
            common-allow-transfer;
    };
    };
 zone "domain13.com" {
    type master;
    file "domain13.com";
    allow-transfer {
            xx.xx.xx.xx;
            2203:d1d0:0:4swd::1;
            common-allow-transfer;
    };
    };
 ..............
```

So question is how can file be merged in linux with adding data from FILE1 to FILE2 only from zone to }; without any other text like // -- ALL LINES BELOW WERE GENERATED --. 
I need to add that data to existing file FILE2 from imported FILE1. Any help?

Comment: `cat file1 file2 > file.new`

Comment: Or `cat file1 >> file2` to add the file1 information to the end of file2.

Comment: @Barmar yes I know that cat can do it, but problem is that it will copy everything from that file1 to file2 with text that is not needed.

Comment: You need to be more specific in the question then. Show sample inputs and the desired results.

Comment: You can use `sed` or `awk` to print a range of lines fitting patterns, and append that.

Comment: `sed -n '/startpattern/,/endpattern/p' file1 >> file2`

Comment: @Barmar // -- ALL LINES BELOW WERE GENERATED --
// -- Some custom text that can be anywhere -- FILE1 have these texts. I need to avoid them and transfer zone "domain............. data to FILE2.

Comment: @Barmar thank you! will try to use sed -n.... with pattern, I think that is what I need.

Comment: Can you fix the indentation so that the `}` that matches `zone` is at the left margin, instead of being indented like the line before it? Then you can use `/^zone/,/^}/p`

Comment: @Barmar no I can't because it is auto generated data, so will be mess to change 500+ records with changing }

Comment: Then you'll have to write a more complex parser in a language like awk or python, because the end of each zone is not a unique pattern. There might be a way to do it with `sed` using the hold space, but it will be difficult if you're not an advanced `sed` user.

Comment: If it's auto-generated, can't you fix the program that generates it?

Comment: @Barmar it is software that do all automations and exports FILE1 contents. All program is encrypted so I can't edit how it exports that data. But will research it also. Thank you for some advises!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the auto-generated text begins with "/" then you could remove those lines using e.g.

```
grep -v "/" file1 >> file2
```

Would that solve your problem?

Comment: Yes thank you, also @Barmar solved it by his tip!